# How to set Swagger ignore id property on Create method? C# ASP.NET Core Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

How can I ask Swagger not to ask id for POST method (creation of entity in DB)?

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "quantity": 0,
  "typeId": 0,
  "brandId": 0
}
```

There is an auto-incrementation in my SQL Server, so I think on frontend it's not necessary to input Id and there will be no field for Id. But is it possible to ask swagger not to show id?

Comment: it is not swagger who is generating but your model which you expecting in post method. generally you should use DTO without id if that it you intension.

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else? Check if this library provides an annotation to mark a property as read-only. Swagger UI won't show read-only properties in request body examples.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way now with now. There are two things you need to do

1. Annotate with SwaggerSchema found in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;

```
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

2. EnableAnnotations in AddSwaggerGen

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.EnableAnnotations();
    });
```

See more about it in the [Documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations)

Answer (score 1):

Create a dedicated create dto:

```
public class CreateDto {

  public class Name { get; set;}
  public int Quantity { get; set;}
  ...
}
```

and in your controller create an instance of your db entity from the incoming `CreateDto` object.

Comment: do I need some mapper from my object to CreateDto? And how should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with JsonIgnore attribute if you don't need to Serialize the model  somewhere else in your project
I tried as below:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Hide { get; set; }
    }
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I need Id to update model, like I should set model with what id I want to change.